# Alarming number of new spam users

Tags: discussion, new-users, spam

I just visited the [Autobiographer badge page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/9/autobiographer), and scrolling through, I was alarmed to find a large number of obviously spam users.

Looking at the links and and bios of these users, they're **pure spam.**

For example:

> Basic Information In Relation To Wordpress You'll Adore 
>  Ecommerce Search Engine Marketing Agency Roi 
>  You Should Use Social Media Shops To Advertise

The names at first look perfectly fine, but, come to think of it, lots of folks prefer to stay anonymous online, so seeing so many first+last names in succession like that, with default avatars, **is abnormal.**

The difficulty here is that they aren't posting, so the community can't really fight it at all.

How do we deal with this?

Comment: "How do we deal with this?" ... why do we need to deal with that? As far as I know this stuff is allowed in the "about me" section. As long as they don't spam anywhere else, there is nothing to do. "seemingly inconspicuous first+last names" ... most likely from a name generator. You can also find those accounts on youtube so spammers and dumb people (conspiracy theory people etc.) look legit when commenting.

Comment: So it doesn't actually matter that hundreds of garbage users fill SO every day?

Comment: Couldn't a ban be applied to their IP(s)? Or are the spammers smarter than that?

Comment: Why should they matter? They currently don't break any rules.

Comment: It's not like they're posting spam posts though. They're harmless compared to the crap that some legimate users post as questions.

Comment: Related on MSE: [Spam Profiles are getting my goat. Could we have better tools for mods to deal with profile spam?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/303746)

Comment: We don't do anything about it. This has been going on for years. Some mods sometimes delete these accounts, but there's too many and it's just a waste of time. The agreed course of action is to just ignore it. Devs should really take care of this

Comment: It doesn't at all. I'm just trying to point out indicators that it's dishonest.

Comment: What is dishonest about the user names? Such user names have been used since the early days of the site. As far as I know the only real restrictions on them are decency related

Comment: I mean, the spammers are being dishonest by pretending to have real common names, but they're not really. No offense intended :)

Comment: @richardec I don't really think that's a problem. My name is not "Just A Newbie" I don't think SO has prohibited anything towards having fake names, or having names that's duplicates to each other (well, if your name is not Jon Skeet).

Comment: Of course, @justANewbie. My point _isn't_ the names though, and I'm sorry to have given that impression if I have. My point is the waste of the system by probably just a few real people.

Comment: Deleting these profiles has been called a "[waste of time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/297999/323179)" by a Stack Exchange employee. I agree that it's scuzzy that spam can get visibility like this, but this is really something that should be done by the system and not moderators. It's tedious and time-consuming to verify that these aren't legitimate accounts (i.e. used here or elsewhere on the network to make non-spam posts). However, I do know that some moderators do edit the profiles. That's why you sometimes see the badge being earned by accounts literally named "Spammer".

Comment: The point about the names is somewhat relevant since it's an indicator that these accounts could all be from the same spammer, or otherwise that there is something systematic about the creation of these accounts. It doesn't matter which language the names are in, but if they're all in the same few languages then that tells us something.

Comment: @Laurel it is a concern for smaller/niche sites and the mods of those sites often do clean-up profiles that mistook an SE site for a free yellow pages listing. I tend to scan the new users on stackapps daily and clean-up but that is more because there are hardly any flags or reviews to handle then a time waster.

Comment: Easy fix, new users should be anonymized until they have answered or asked their first question with a positive score. However, if its generating profit for the powers that be, why would they fix it? At stackoverflow we have a user base of  \*cough\* 14 million  (mostly spam users). Its kind of like facebook and twitter bots, why do anything when they can charge advertisers more on those metrics, or launch an IPO with better figures

Comment: I wonder if _that_ is the real reason.

Comment: How about a Capcha (a complicated one)?

Comment: Well... isn't there already a captcha when registering? It doesn't need to be particularly complicated, if the quoted spam is any indication of the spammer's intelligence level...

Comment: Rejecting a new user just because it is a spam bot is not “welcoming”.

Comment: @holydragon StackOverflow already has something much better built-in: it's called *privileges*. Modifying the autobiography (or anything else, even replacing the default identicon by an image) could be a privilege that is granted only after a user has provided a few answers that received upvotes. That would be a much more thorough sanity check than a captcha.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin And additionally remove all users that only registered and didn't do anything within say 6 months.

Comment: Checked a link, profiles look legit. Also, seems like big number of users -> more profit for SO managers, so

Comment: What about profiles that contain unallowed content like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17733505/vognsen-dillard) ? (granted, there is no link to an external website, but some profiles may have those)

Comment: Edit from my previous post : there is indeed a link to a porn site in the profile

Comment: I know they're 'not doing any harm if they're not posting.' But can we tell if those accounts are boosting (voting on things)? Also, would it ever become a performance issue on some level?

Comment: Accounts without rep cannot cast real votes. At best, (worse?) they can be used to bolster SE's marketing metrics.

Comment: @CVerica they can't cast votes until they have 15 rep, but even so, we can see if and how many times they vote (but not _what_ they vote): scroll to the bottom of their activity page ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17733668/wulff-bland?tab=topactivity)).

Comment: @Machavity out of curiosity - why did you remove this Q from HMP?

Comment: @richardec While the question is perfectly valid, we also don't want to draw additional attention to it.

Comment: Fine with me. But what is the reason for this @Machavity, if I may? ;)

Comment: @richardec We don't really have time to police new profiles being created. Letting folks know that would be to invite more of that behavior

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Deleting these users is [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) by [animuson](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/141525/animuson) on MSE; ([Delete old, unloved, users better](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146458/delete-old-unloved-users-better))

To quote:

> I have confirmed that we do not currently run any automatic deletions on any sort of schedule and we do not have any plans to reinstate such a schedule in the future. Writing queries to detect users to qualify for deletion while maintaining the necessary exclusions is too resource-intensive to run through our scheduler, even at the previous rate limit of only 1,000 users every week.

By my estimates from earlier in the month there's [at most 1.4m users that](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1527788/users-scheduled-for-deletion-that-can-spam) *[might](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1527788/users-scheduled-for-deletion-that-can-spam)* [be spam](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1527788/users-scheduled-for-deletion-that-can-spam) and could be safely deleted (i.e. no posts, 1 reputation, not logged in for 6 months etc.) On the other hand, you've got to go actively looking for them, so they're not doing too much harm.

As you can see the original question is over 9 years old now... this has never been deemed that important.

**How do we deal with this?**

tl;dr - we don't.

Comment: Well, it might be easy to get through captcha then, but why then have it at all if it doesn't prevent bots? Or by any chance it's few millions of real people posting spam on their bio?

Comment: Related follow-up: [an answer from staff to "As per the new data retention policy, when will inactive accounts now be deleted?" in 2018](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/310516/241919) "*All users who matched this criteria as of June 2018 were deleted as part of a batch process. However, we did not reinstate automatic deletion. We may continue to do mass deletions like this as batches in the future.*"